# Running out of memory on Deep Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, dataset, data-science

I was coding a model with Tensorflow and I run out of memory on my PC, then I try the same on Google Colab and I got the same result.

My dataset shape was innitially this:

```
(541909, 8)
```

The problem is that my dataset has one row called `'Description'` and seems like that:

```
0     WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER
1                    WHITE METAL LANTERN
2         CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER
3    KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE
4         RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART
...
```

My dataset has over 500000 rows and the `'Description'` column has over 3500 unique values, so, in order to train my model, I use `pandas.get_dummies()` function:

```
dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset, columns=["Description"])
```

Using this, dataset shape change to:

```
(541909, 3936)
```

I'm sure that this huge amount of data is part of the problem but i not sure how I could avoid it, any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: This `Description` column seems to be describing products, is that correct? Is it a possibility to group products in categories? That should leave you with a categorical column of a much smaller dimension

Comment: Additionally, if this column is so highly diverse it is likely that it won't contribute much to the learning of the model. You may even want to consider dropping out the column completely, if it is not feasible to consolidate it into more usable information

Comment: @Tim Stack, Description column has around 4000 values, so It will be annoying try to group them.

Comment: I also think on just droppping it out. But I dind't because I though that quantity sold would have a huge relation to the product that is sold, btw I will drop it out and see the results

Comment: You could try text-based category prediction, to avoid having to group all 4000 values. This will still require you to categorise a fair few by hand, but it might give you good enough results to avoid having to categorise all 4k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a solution. You should load your data and transform it using the `tf.data.Dataset` [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset).

As few comments says that you will have to shorten your `Description` column, having a threshold value so to say. But Using the `Dataset` pipeline you will be sure that it won't load complete dataset into memory but only one `Batch` at a time.

Tensorflow also recommends using this API for input pipeline. It will be a learning curve using it instead of `pandas`. But I will recommend doing it for better performance. There are a lot of tutorials. I will suggest to follow a tutorial that is loading the dataset directly in to `tf.data.Dataset`.